# Complete Intersection does not lie in a hyperplane?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose there are $k$, $k \leq n-2$, irreducible hypersurfaces of in $\mathbb{P}^n,n \geq 3$ cut out by $F_1,\cdots, F_{k}$ with degree $d_i \geq 2$ and they form a complete intersection which is connected. I guess their complete intersection does not lie in any hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$, it this true and how to prove this?

My idea is to use adjunction formula, the canonical line bundle of the intersection is 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}(-n-1+d_1+\cdots+d_k)
\end{equation}

where $-n-1+d_1+\cdots+d_k$ could be positive or $0$ or negative, what does this mean? I want to pull back section of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ to the intersection to show they do not vanish, but do not know how to show this.

Comment: Complete intersection means any hypersurface containing the variety is of the form $\sum a_iF_i=0$  with $a_i$ homogeneous polynomials of the appropriate degree. If $\deg F_i\geq 2$ for all $i$, no linear form can be expressed as above.